# An airplane is ﬂying on a horizontal path. Find P(point) changing with respect to θ

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> An airplane is ﬂying on a horizontal path at a height of
> 3800 ft, as shown in the accompanying ﬁgure. At what rate
> is the distance $s$ between the airplane and the ﬁxed point
> $P$ changing with respect to $θ$ when $θ = 30\deg$ ? Express the
> answer in units of feet/degree.
> [image]

I had tried two way, first way wasn't satisfied to me (it was looking wrong to me).

1.
$$\sin (\theta) = \frac{s}{3800}$$
$$=>\cos (\theta) = \frac{\frac{ds}{d\theta}}{3800}$$
$$\frac{ds}{d\theta}=3290.89653436 feet/degree$$

2.

$$sin \theta = \frac{s}{3800}$$
$$s=\sin (30) \times 3800$$
$$s=1900$$

I found value of $s$ (hypotenuse) somehow. The question said to find `P changing with respect to θ`. But, how can I manage/rearrange it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have written the expression wrong. $$\sin {\theta}=\frac {3800}{s}$$
After this you have to differentiate to find $\frac {ds}{d\theta}$.

Comment: $sin\theta= height/hypotenuse $ 3800 is height

Comment: Yes, I know. That is why it should be 3800/s

Comment: But, why? Could you please explain?

Comment: You said it yourself. $\sin{\theta}=$ height/hypotenuse, here height is 3800 and hypotenuse is $s$.

Comment: Ohh! Sorry! I was sleepy. I was looking from downside lol